# generated crc in delphi differs from crc in javascript

Tags: javascript, delphi, crc

I am having some trouble converting a javascript function to delphi. Everything is working ok except the crc part.

This is a long question, but I really need help. This software will help me in my job. I'm using Delphi XE3.

First, I will post the delphi function so I can show where is the problem.

```
    function getChlg(c: DWORD; slt: string; s1,s2: Char): string;
    const
     n = 4;
    var
     arr: array of char;
     start,Endd,t: Integer;
     m: Extended;
     crc: DWORD;
     chlg, astr: string;
     //loop vars
     i,j,k: integer;
    begin
     start:=Ord(s1);
     Endd:=Ord(s2);
     SetLength(arr, n);
     m:=Math.Power(((Endd - start) + 1),n);

     for i := 0 to 3 do
      arr[i]:=s1;

     for i := 0 to round(m)-1 do
     begin

      for j:= n-1 downto 0 do
      begin
       t:=Ord(arr[j]);
       Inc(t);
       arr[j]:=Chr(t);
       if (Ord(arr[j]) <= Endd) then
        break
       else
        arr[j]:=s1;
      end; //j loop end

      chlg:='';

      for j := 0 to 3 do
       chlg:=chlg + arr[j];

      astr:=chlg + slt;
      crc:=0;
      crc:= crc xor (-1);

      for k:= 1 to Length(astr) do // here.. crc value is incorrect
       crc:=(crc shr 8) xor StrToInt('$'+Copy(table, (((crc xor Ord(astr[k])) and $000000FF) * 9)+1, 8) );

      crc:=crc xor (-1);
      crc:=Abs(crc);

      if crc = c then
       break;
    end;//i loop end

    Result:=chlg;
    end;
```

You probably noticed that the table var is not declared, this is because I've made the table a global var. The table content is too long for being declared, so I created a file, put the content in there and load this file into a TStringList, and pass the Text to the table var.

To test, use `GetChlg(866495222,'NlH3lm0X','v','z');` . Will return vvvv in delphi and xxxz in javascript.

This happens because the main loop `for i := 0 to round(m)-1 do` have to stop when the crc is equal the C parameter, but this never happens in delphi, the loop execute till the end, giving me a wrong result.

If you edit this `for i := 0 to round(m)-1 do` to this `for i := 1 to 314 do`, and use the test parameters, will return xxxz, but the crc still incorrect >.<.

look the "for k" loop log:

```
--delphi--
[01]crc: 1931733372
[02]crc: 119465968
[03]crc: -1805441693
[04]crc: 1833535438
[05]crc: -304756057
[06]crc: 207343346
[07]crc: 733479260
[08]crc: -584661816
[09]crc: -781827787
[10]crc: 1700904839
[11]crc: 1432373136
[12]crc: -1779815739

--js--
[01]crc: -1943803524
[02]crc: -119412752
[03]crc: 479980277
[04]crc: 2098922843
[05]crc: 1839267822
[06]crc: 64701171
[07]crc: 1555083590
[08]crc: 540226818
[09]crc: -1440055446
[10]crc: 1640939484
[11]crc: -1445109524
[12]crc: 866495221    --->crc = C parameter
```

here is the javascript function:

```
function chlg(c,slt,s1,s2){
    var table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
    var n = 4;
    var start = s1.charCodeAt(0);
    var end   = s2.charCodeAt(0);
    var arr = new Array(n);
    var m = Math.pow(((end - start) + 1),n);

    for (var i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = s1;

    for (var i=0; i<m-1; i++){
        for(var j=n-1; j>=0;--j) {
            var t = arr[j].charCodeAt(0);
            t++; 
            arr[j] = String.fromCharCode(t);
            if (arr[j].charCodeAt(0)<=end) {
                break;
            } else { 
                arr[j] = s1 ;
            }
        }

        var chlg = arr.join("");
        var str = chlg + slt;
        var crc = 0;
        var crc = crc ^ (-1);

        for( var k = 0, iTop = str.length; k < iTop; k++ ){ 
            crc = (crc >> 8) ^ ("0x" + table.substr(((crc ^ str.charCodeAt(k) ) & 0x000000FF) * 9, 8));
        }

        crc =  crc ^ (-1);
        crc = Math.abs(crc);

        if (crc == parseInt(c)){
            break;
        }
    }

return crc;
}
```

Comment: For starters, in Delphi, `for i := 0 to round(m)-1 do` will stop *after* executing the iteration where `i` equals `round(m)-1`. In JS, `for (var i=0; i<m-1; i++)` will stop *before* executing the iteration where `i` equals `m-1`. There might be additional issues with signed/unsigned integers and integer sizes (Delphi's Dword is 32-bits, JS numbers are larger).

Comment: For future questions, be more specific. In this particular case: which CRC are you calculating? Arnoud figured out it is supposed to be CRC-32, but that should have been in the question.

Comment: *"The table content is too long for being declared, "* No it's not. You can declare long strings by cutting them in < 256 character pieces. `var x: string = 'long string' + 'other long string' + '...';`

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers Better yet the code itself should be documented with a description of what it does, what the variables are, etc. A year from now functions called "getChlg" and variables with names like "c" and "s1" and "s2" aren't going to mean anything at all.

Comment: @alcalde a year from now? 2 weeks from now. At the most (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help me, but I finally solved this. I was searching for other javascript function to generate the crc32, just to test if the result will be equal.

For my surprise, the result still different, but, the function that I found was using `crc >>> 8` and not `crc >> 8`. So I already knew that the error in delphi is the shr operator. (in the javascript function, I changed the ">>>" to ">>" and worked).

Searching again (now I was searching more about the shr command) I found one page explaining about the difference of the shift right operation in delphi and c.

Anyway, to make my code work like a charm, I just have to use the **sar** instruction instead **shr**. So, to make the code work, just change this:

```
for k:= 1 to Length(astr) do
 crc:=(crc shr 8) xor StrToInt('$'+Copy(table, (((crc xor Ord(astr[k])) and $000000FF) * 9)+1, 8) );
```

To this:

```
for k:= 1 to Length(astr) do
begin
 x:=Copy(table, (((crc xor Ord(astr[k])) and $000000FF) * 9)+1, 8);
 asm
  mov eax, crc
  sar eax, 8    //using sar instead (crc shr 8)
  xor eax, x
  mov crc, eax
 end;
end;
```

[here](http://galfar.vevb.net/wp/2009/shift-right-delphi-vs-c/) is the link of the page that explain the difference of shr and sar instructions.

Comment: You don't preserve eax. That looks very dubious. Put your sar code into a seperate function. Don't mix everything into one single function. Modularisation is not a new idea.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You do not need to preserve eax, in local asm..end; blocks: it is by design a volatile register. eax,ecx,edx are volatile within blocks.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Does the compiler and optimiser  understand that at the level of a local asm block within a function?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is [by convention](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Inline_Assembly_Code): the compiler does not have to make any guess about the asm itself - "An asm statement must preserve the EDI, ESI, ESP, EBP, and EBX registers, but can freely modify the EAX, ECX, and EDX registers". So, about register allocation, the Delphi 32 bit compiler handles any `asm..end` block as a function call, but opcodes are inlined to the function body.

Answer (score 5):

The JavaScript is an over-complicated version of the crc32() algorithm as implemented in the zlib/zip library.

It is overcomplicated because of JavaScript itself, which is too high level to process as expected such bit-oriented process. For instance, all those `crc = crc ^ (-1)` are to force the content to be 32 bit unsigned, which is not needed in Delphi: you just use a `cardinal` variable. The fact that it uses a string table is also something awfull, but pretty common in the javascript work.

The easiest is to use the version shipped with the `ZLib.pas` unit.

Here is a short version of this crc32() in pure pascal, using not a fixed table but a once-generated table.

```
var
  crc32Tab : array [0..255] of cardinal;


{
  Generate a table for a byte-wise 32-bit CRC calculation on the polynomial:
  x^32+x^26+x^23+x^22+x^16+x^12+x^11+x^10+x^8+x^7+x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1.

  Polynomials over GF(2) are represented in binary, one bit per coefficient,
  with the lowest powers in the most significant bit.  Then adding polynomials
  is just exclusive-or, and multiplying a polynomial by x is a right shift by
  one.  If we call the above polynomial p, and represent a byte as the
  polynomial q, also with the lowest power in the most significant bit (so the
  byte 0xb1 is the polynomial x^7+x^3+x+1), then the CRC is (q*x^32) mod p,
  where a mod b means the remainder after dividing a by b.

  This calculation is done using the shift-register method of multiplying and
  taking the remainder.  The register is initialized to zero, and for each
  incoming bit, x^32 is added mod p to the register if the bit is a one (where
  x^32 mod p is p+x^32 = x^26+...+1), and the register is multiplied mod p by
  x (which is shifting right by one and adding x^32 mod p if the bit shifted
  out is a one).  We start with the highest power (least significant bit) of
  q and repeat for all eight bits of q.

  The table is simply the CRC of all possible eight bit values.  This is all
  the information needed to generate CRC's on data a byte at a time for all
  combinations of CRC register values and incoming bytes.
}
procedure InitCrc32Tab;
var i,n,crc: cardinal;
begin // this code is 49 bytes long, generating a 1KB table
  for i := 0 to 255 do begin
    crc := i;
    for n := 1 to 8 do
      if (crc and 1)<>0 then
        // $edb88320 from polynomial p=(0,1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,12,16,22,23,26)
        crc := (crc shr 1) xor $edb88320 else
        crc := crc shr 1;
    CRC32Tab[i] := crc;
  end;
end;

function UpdateCrc32(aCRC32: cardinal; inBuf: pointer; inLen: integer) : cardinal;
var i: integer;
begin 
  result := not aCRC32;
  for i := 1 to inLen do begin
    result := crc32Tab[byte(result xor pByte(inBuf)^)] xor (result shr 8);
    inc(PByte(inBuf));
  end;
  result := not result;
end;
```

You will find several other versions (also enhanced for speed) in [our source code repository](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZip.pas).

Comment: Thanks to the proud anonymous down-voter! Please add a comment to state what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: It's just a guess but the reason may be, this is not an answer to the question, which presumably is *"why does not this code work like this other code?"*. Since actually there are no questions asked, anyone can think others' understanding of the issue is wrong.

Comment: 1. Beautiful example of documenting code! One of the nicest Delphi examples of documented code I've seen in quite some time.

Comment: Languages can never be too high-level. ;-)

Comment: @alcalde (comment is from official ZLib code - I did not cut it for completeness) Yes, languages can never be too high-level. The highest level programming language should indeed be "abracadabra".

Answer (score 0):

CRC doesn't describe a single algorithm, but an algorithmic approach to generating a checksum.   You'll have to implement the same algorithm on both sides, or find some other library or developer who's already done the same for you.

I had to do the same to create an identically-implemented CRC algorithm in C# for a C# client to a Delphi server program.   It was a pain, and it burned away the better part of a day, but it's been working okay ever since.

Good Google skills may prove crucial here.   Good luck.

Comment: "Good luck" is not an answer to the question, I'm afraid.

Comment: AFAICS, there is no question.

Comment: Even if there was a question, this would not be the answer. Unless the question was, "Please tell me a story about the time when you wrote some code."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan    I really don't understand this StackOverflow holier-than-thouism:  the poster did not understand that all CRC algorithms did not generate identical results, or that he would have to have identical implementations on both sides.  That was useful information to him.   The fact that I had mentioned that I had faced a similar dilemma, and that it took me about a day to resolve?   Jeez...  this is a community mutual help forum, and I really do think the answer was helpful to the poster.   At least as helpful as code to implement a CRC on only one side of of his client-server pair

Comment: It might be helpful, but it's not an answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: *this is a community mutual help forum*  - Wrong, Stackoverflow [is NOT a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum).  And as per SO rules every post in the answer field must be answering a question. I had the same problem is not an answer.